Can we eliminate the $c_{n-1}$ term in the recurrance relation $c_n+f_nc_{n-1}+g_nc_{n-2}=0$ via transformation?
For second order linear differential equations of the form
\begin{align}
y''+f(x)y'+g(x)y=0,
\end{align}
we can eliminate the $y'$ term via a transformation, e.g. $y=\exp(-1/2 \smallint f(x)\mathrm dx)z$ to
\begin{align}
z''+\left(g-\frac14f^2-\frac12f'\right)z=0.
\end{align}
Does an analogous transformation exist for the recurrence relation
\begin{align}
c_n+f_nc_{n-1}+g_nc_{n-2}=0?
\end{align}
I've tried a few transformation to no avail. To get something that makes the $c_n$ and $c_{n-1}$ or $c_{n-2}$ and $c_{n-1}$ terms commingle seems to necessitate adding/removing a degree to/from the equation. E.g. $c_n=\alpha_n a_n+\beta_n a_{n-1}$ increases the order by 1 and $c_n/c_{n-1}=a_n$ decreases the order by 1.
